# Delete duplicate scheme from Xcode

Tags: xcode

My app having multiple target and accidentally i have duplicate one of my target So Is there any way  to delete that duplicate scheme from the XCode scheme list.

Answer (score 18):

> Delete duplicate scheme from Xcode ?

Go to xcode -> Click on your Target -> Click on Manage Schemes
[image]

You have a list of your scheme -> you just have to delete the duplicated scheme
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but want to know where xcode store these scheme coz i have added duplicate scheme in develop branch but if i change the branch to master branch, in the same branch i am getting same scheme.

Answer (score 7):

Click on your target next to the play/stop button on the top left and choose "Manage Schemes", select the scheme you want and press backspace. This will delete the scheme

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, but with regard to working in a Workspace. After trying to add a Today Extension to my workspace, Xcode autogenerated a scheme for my Xcode Project, resulting in duplicate scheme names, which then looked like this:

```
<App Name> (<App Name> Workspace)
<App Name> (<App Name> Xcode Project)
```

Since I'm working in a cocoapod architecture, I deleted the Xcode Project scheme, and everything is back to normal, app works fine, etc. Wanted to add that since I hadn't seen anyone have that specific duplicate name problem.